# Why does the order of elements affect the line of best fit/linear regression?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Consider the following y-values ($(0,y_0),(1,y_1),...$):

$$580,382,854,193,128,901,283,294,854,490$$

Plotting the linear regression gives the following formula:

$$y = 4.5x + 475.8$$

However, switching around the order of the y-values, like so:

$$580,382,854,854,128,901,283,294,193,490$$

Gives the following line of best fit:

$$y = -35.6x + 656.1$$

Why does the order matter when it comes to a line of best fit? The elements are the same and the algorithm I am using has no interaction between x- and y-variables:

```
sx = 0; sy = 0; stt = 0; sts = 0;
yArray = {}; //ten numbers from above
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    sx = sx + i;
    sy = sy + yArray[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    t = i - (sx / 10);
    stt = stt + (t * t);
    sts = sts + (t * yArray[i]);
}
slope = sts / stt;
intercept = (sy - (sx * slope)) / 10;
```

There's nothing like `sx + sy` or `sx * sy`, etc. I just don't see where the order matters here.

Comment: Because you're choosing different points. Consider: The line through (0,0) and (1,1) is $y=x$; the line through (0,1) and (1,0) is $y=1-x$.

Comment: As for your programming, changing the order of the $y$ coordinates changes the value of sts.

Comment: You can't switch the $y$ values without switching the corresponding $x$ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are using must somehow assess the association between x and y. Otherwise, it can't give you a regression line. 
(I believe @CarlHeckman has put his finger on it in his second
Comment.)

By changing the order of the y's without making a corresponding change in the order of the x's, you are destroying the bivariate nature of the data. Consider the following fake data:

```
 Subject:  1  2  3  4  5
 x:        2  4  6  8 10
 y1:       0  1  2  3  4
```

Here the x's and y's give points on an ascending line. Their
correlation is 1.

But if I mix the y-values around, I destroy the 'pairing' that
traces back to the subjects. Now the plotted (x, y) points no
longer lie in a straight line. Their correlation is $r = 0.6$.

```
 Subject:  1  2  3  4  5
 x:        2  4  6  8 10
 y2:       0  3  2  1  4
```

And if I put the y's in reverse order, then I get a line that goes
the other direction, and the correlation is -1.

```
 Subject:  1  2  3  4  5
 x:        2  4  6  8 10
 y3:       4  3  2  1  0
```

Changing the correlation changes the slope of the regression line. Here are plots of the original and changed data.

[image]